# Alternative google analytics tracking code?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm using the following code to add Google analytics to a website.

The problem is... I don't have access to the source files, only an edit box in a (very old) custom CMS.

Pasting in `<scripts>` works fine generally, but they have a templating solution in place which uses square brackets (`[`,`]`), and the GA code is messing it all up.

I can think of 2 possible solutions:

1. Some sort of alternative syntax so I can omit the brackets from the tracking code
2. A completely different (older?) method of including the tracking code. Does this exist?

**My existing GA code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have the chance to host a file outside the CMS? If so then You could place the code in a JS file and in the CMS simply use it as external script.

Comment: good thinking david. I *can* do that. That will pick up the current page (not the src of the script) correct? If so, please move to an answer and I'll award you your nerd-points ;-)

Comment: As far as I understood yes. Quoting google: "Use a common include or template to paste the code above instead of manually adding it to every page". However I never tried

Comment: Awesome. A much simpler solution than I expected

Comment: @david - pssst... turn your 1st comment into an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being able to host a file outside the CMS, you can put the tracking code in a separate file and include it as an external javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You could try substituting in HTML entities

```
[ = &#91;
] = &#93;
```

so when they display in the browser they hopefully get interpreted correctly - I've seen that kind of approach work with this kind of issue in template languages before.

Failing that see http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-track-google-analytics/ - there's a few old school GA script option documented there.
Cheers
Ben

Comment: Doesn't look like you can substitute HTML entities in a script; just tried and got "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL".  I'll try david's solution next (b/c its easy), but then I'll give the alternatives from your link. Thanks!